# LyX and classicthesis: Linespacing of notes within floating table like footnotes

Tags: tables, lyx, line-spacing, classicthesis

I use LyX and the classicthesis template. Now I want to add some lines of notes below a floating table (within the floating environment). In principle, this works without any problems, but the linespacing is the same as in the text. This looks odd because I also set the textsize to "smaller".

I want those notes to look like footnotes (obviously not at the bottom of the page but below the table) in terms of size and linespacing. Does anyone know the exact linespacing of footnotes in classicthesis so that I can apply it manually?

Or is there a more general solution so that I do not have to change size and linespacing by hand?

Comment: I would simply suggest `\linespread{1}`. I hope `classicthesis` did not fiddle with that as well.

Comment: You could of course just use a footnote instead of doing stuff manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "LyX and the `classicthesis` template"? Do you use the `classicthesis` package? What document class are you using?

Comment: Setting linespread equal to one solves my problem. For some reason this did not look like the footnotes before but now does.

Comment: Interestingly, setting linespread equal to 1 only works if there is only one paragraph or if a put another element (such as vertical space of 0cm) after the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I guess with the `threeparttable` and its `tablenotes` environment, it's more as you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!htbp]\centering
 \caption{An Interesting Table}
 \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
    \toprule\midrule
    \thead{First\\ head} & \thead{Second\\ head} & \thead{Third\\ Head} & \thead{Fourth\\ Head}\\
     \midrule
    Blah & Blah & Blah\tnote{a} & Blah\tnote{b} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
   \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
 \item[a] Blahblahblah.%
  \item[b] Fiddle dee dee!
 \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
    \label{table2}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]